# Program Bugs with large sequences (C)

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to code the Waterman algorithm in C.
Now when the length of the sequence exceeds 35 the program just lags.
I have no idea where to start looking, tried but got nothing worked out.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// Max Function Prototype.
int maxfunction(int, int);

// Prototype of the random Sequences generator Function.
void gen_random(char *, const int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {    
    // Looping variable and Sequences.
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    char *X, *Y;
    int length1, length2;

    // Time Variables.
    time_t beginning_time, end_time;

    // Getting lengths of sequences
    printf("Please provide the length of the first Sequence\n");
    scanf("%d", &length1);

    printf("Please provide the length of the second Sequence\n");
    scanf("%d", &length2);

    X = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * length1);
    Y = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * length2);

    int m = length1 + 1;
    int n = length2 + 1;
    int L[m][n];
    int backtracking[m + n];

    gen_random(X, length1);
    gen_random(Y, length2);

    printf("First Sequence\n");
    for (i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", X[i]);
    }
    printf("\nSecond Sequence\n");
    for (i = 0; i < length2; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", Y[i]);
    }

    // Time calculation beginning.
    beginning_time = clock();

    // Main Part--Core of the algorithm.
    for (i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0) {
                L[i][j] = 0;
            } else
            if (X[i-1] == Y[j-1]) {
                L[i][j] = L[i-1][j-1] + 1;
                backtracking[i] = L[i-1][j-1];
            } else {
                L[i][j] = maxfunction(L[i-1][j], L[i][j-1]);
                backtracking[i] = maxfunction(L[i-1][j], L[i][j-1]);
            }
        }
    }

    // End time calculation.
    end_time = clock();

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf(" ( ");
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", L[i][j]);
        }
        printf(")\n");
    }

    // Printing out the result of backtracking.
    printf("\n");
    for (k = 0; k < m; k++) {
        printf("%d\n", backtracking[k]);
    }

    printf("Consumed time: %lf", (double)(end_time - beginning_time));
    return 0;
}

// Max Function.
int maxfunction(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}

// Random Sequence Generator Function.
void gen_random(char *s, const int len) {
    int i = 0;
    static const char alphanum[] = "ACGT";

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        s[i] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
    }
    s[len] = 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't know what kind of performance to *expect* from this code.  What do you expect, and why?

Comment: I am interested in calculating how much time it takes to find the common sequence, then compare it with a parallel version.

Comment: You say the program lags when "the length of the sequence exceeds 35", but there are two sequences in the code. Please clarify. Also, can you give some times to show what kind of "lag" you're talking about?

Comment: The point is that you have to know how long you *expect* the algorithm to take before you can complain that it's "lagging" (being *unusually* slow).  Specifically, what is the time complexity of the code?

Comment: Yes, there are two sequences, thus the comparison.
 
By lag I mean the program just stops at generating the two sequences, it doesn't generate the matrix, print the resulting sequence.

Comment: "Lagging" means "slowing down", but it seems now you mean that it halts (also called "hanging").  Also you only just told us *where in the code* that happens!  -1, show some effort.

Comment: Comparison to what? You stated that the length of *the* sequence exceeds 35, implying only one sequence, yet there are two. Give us some numbers instead of vagueness..

Comment: Try writing `static` in front of `int L[m][n];`.  If this fixes things, the problem is that you were allocating too large an array on the stack.  Google this for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you null terminate the sequence in `gen_random` with `s[len] = 0;`, you should allocate 1 more byte for each sequence:

```
X = malloc(sizeof(*X) * (length1 + 1));
Y = malloc(sizeof(*Y) * (length2 + 1));
```

But since you define variable length arrays for other variables, you might as well define these as:

```
char X[length1 + 1], Y[length2 + 1];
```

Yet something else is causing a crash on my laptop: your nested loops iterate from `i = 0` to `i <= m`, and `j = 0` to `j <= n`.  That's one step too many, you index out of bounds into `L`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
```

The resulting code executes very quickly, its complexity is `O(m*n)` in both time and space, but `m` and `n` are reasonably small at `35`. It runs in less than 50ms for 1000 x 1000.

Whether it implements Smith-Waterman's algorithm correctly is another question.

Comment: Yes indeed !...thanks :)

Comment: Will take that into consideration and check if it is correctly implemented, thanks for noting that Charlie.

Comment: do you have any idea why I get a segmentation fault at a length of 1500 and above ?

Comment: Yes: you define `int L[m][n];` with automatic storage.  if `m` and `n` are 1500, `L` will request 9MB of stack space, which may be too much for your environment.  Define `L` this way: `int (*L)[n] = malloc(m * sizeof(*L));`

Comment: Made my day, working like a charm...hats off !